# SQL GROUP BY on a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that will return results from 2 tables into 1 using a UNION ALL, which all works as I need it to. However I need to run a GROUP BY and an ORDER BY on the returned dataset however I am getting many errors and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT ProductID, Quantity 
FROM BasketItems 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ProductID, Quantity 
FROM OrderItems
```

This will return a results set such as this:

```
ProductID  Quantity  
15         2
20         2
15         1
8          5
5          1
```

I then want to run a `GROUP BY` on the `ProductID` field and then finally an `ORDER BY DESC` on the `Quantity` field. So in the final output, this particular results set will finally result in this:

```
ProductID
8
15
20
5
```

I can then run queries on this result set as I usually do

**EDIT:**

As stated above, but maybe not implied enough is that I will need to run queries on the returned results, which isn't working as you cannot run a query on a set of results that have an ORDER BY clause (so far as I gathered from the error list)

If you want more information on the problem, here it is:

From this results set, I want to get the products from the product table that they relate to

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ProductID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ProductID, Quantity  
        FROM BasketItems  
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT ProductID, Quantity  
        FROM OrderItems 
    ) v
    GROUP BY ProductID
    ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC
)
```

However, I get this error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

The output of products need to be in the order that they are returned in the sub query (By quantity)

Comment: In the final result set do you only need the productId or do you still want quantity to show?

Comment: @bluefeet I only need the ProductID in the final result set

Comment: introduction of this new table `Products` changes the question a bit - will need to edit my attempt at the answer

Comment: @whytheq Yeah, I forgot to elaborate on that point, I didn't realise that it was going to make a difference, I did mention it briefly in a one line sentence but didn't make a point of it. My apologies

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT Products.*
FROM Products
     INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ProductID, Sum(Quantity) as QuantitySum
    from
    (
        SELECT ProductID, Quantity  
        FROM BasketItems  
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT ProductID, Quantity  
        FROM OrderItems 
    ) v
    GROUP BY ProductID
) ProductTotals
    ON Products.ID = ProductTotals.ProductID
ORDER BY QuantitySum DESC
```

Comment: Please see edit to post, I should have elaborated this more in the first place but I thought that I could run a query straight off the answer posted

Comment: The edit that you just did has some errors mentioning invalid column name for ProductID and ProductName

Comment: Latest edit, still not working, error on second to last line, invalid column name ProductID again.

Comment: See edit.  You could do it without the second subquery, but that depends on how many columns you have in your products table.

Answer (score 3):

will this work?

```
SELECT ProductID
    from
    (
        SELECT ProductID, Quantity  
        FROM BasketItems  
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT ProductID, Quantity  
        FROM OrderItems 
    ) temp
    GROUP BY temp.ProductID
    ORDER BY SUM(temp.Quantity) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cte version (no live test so please excuse blunders)

**EDIT**

```
;WITH myInitialdata_cte(ProductID,Quantity)
AS
    (
    SELECT ProductID, Quantity FROM BasketItems
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT ProductID, Quantity  FROM OrderItems 
    )
SELECT b.ID
FROM 
     myInitialdata_cte a
     INNER JOIN Products b ON
         a.ProductID = b.ID
GROUP BY ProductID
ORDER BY SUM(a.Quantity) DESC
```

Comment: Works, however please see edit to post, I've elaborated on a point that I should have elaborated upon

Comment: no worries  - I've had a go at editing - atleast this gives you an idea of what CTEs look like